# Since the NFL changed to the 6 team playoff format, what is the best and worst record for each rank 1-6?

Tags: american-football, nfl, ranking

What is the best and worst record in each position?

Comment: Are you asking about regular season record?

Comment: Take a look at the answer I put up

Comment: yes regulat season record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From 1990 to 2019, the NFL playoffs included 6 teams from each conference. Note that in 2020 the league [expanded](https://www.cbssports.com/nfl/news/nfl-owners-approve-playoff-expansion-for-2020-season-adding-one-team-per-conference/) playoffs teams from 6 to 7 in each conference, so this answer doesn't include any teams from the 2020-21 season onwards.

Here are the list of best *regular season* records for each team:

- #1 Seed record: 16-0 by

  - [2007](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2007/) New England Patriots 16-0
- #2 Seed record: 14-2 by

  - [1998](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1998/) Atlanta Falcons
  - [2004](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2004/) New England Patriots
- #3 Seed record: 13-3 by

  - [2011](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2011/) New Orleans Saints
  - [2019](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2019/) New Orleans Saints
- #4 Seed record: 13-3 by

  - [1999](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1999/) Tennessee Titans
- #5 Seed record: 12-4 by

  - [2001](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2001/) San Francisco 49ers
  - [2003](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2003/) Tennessee Titans
  - [2005](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2005/) Jacksonville Jaguars
  - [2008](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2008/) Indianapolis Colts
  - [2010](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2010/) Baltimore Ravens
  - [2011](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2011/) Pittsburgh Steelers
  - [2013](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2013/) San Francisco 49ers
  - [2016](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2016/) Oakland Raiders
  - [2018](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2018/) Los Angeles Chargers
- #6 Seed record: 11-5 by

  - [2005](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2005/) Pittsburgh Steelers
  - [2008](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2008/) Baltimore Ravens
  - [2009](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2009/) Philadelphia Eagles
  - [2010](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2010/) New York Jets
  - [2013](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2013/) New Orleans Saints
  - [2014](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2014/) Detroit Lions

Worst *regular season* records:

- #1 Seed record: 11-5 by

  - [1992](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1992/) Pittsburgh Steelers
  - [2002](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2002/) Oakland Raiders
- #2 Seed record: 10-6 by

  - [1993](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1993/) San Francisco 49ers
  - [2006](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2006/) New Orleans Saints
- #3 Seed record: 9-7 by

  - [1990](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1990/) Cincinnati Bengals
  - [1999](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1999/) Seattle Seahawks
- #4 Seed record: 7-9 by

  - [2010](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2010/) Seattle Seahawks
- #5 Seed record: 8-8 by

  - [1999](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1999/) Dallas Cowboys
  - [2004](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2004/) St. Louis Rams
- #6 Seed record: 8-8 by

  - [1990](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1990/) New Orleans Saints
  - [1991](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1991/) New York Jets
  - [1999](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1999/) Detroit Lions
  - [2004](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2004/) Minnesota Vikings
  - [2006](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2006/) New York Giants

In terms of *playoffs*, the best appearance for each seed is a Super Bowl:

- #1 Seed: Super Bowl Champions, ex [2015-16 Denver Broncos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_50)
- #2 Seed: Super Bowl Champions, ex [2018-19 New England Patriots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_LIII)
- #3 Seed: Super Bowl Champions, ex [2006-07 Indianapolis Colts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_XLI)
- #4 Seed: Super Bowl Champions, ex [2012-13 Baltimore Ravens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_XLVII)
- #5 Seed: Super Bowl Champions, ex [2007-08 New York Giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_XLII)
- #6 Seed: Super Bowl Champions, ex [2010-11 Green Bay Packers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_XLV)

And when it comes to worst playoffs performances, all seeds have lost on the first round of their games.